# Why Selenium not recognised class with space in the name using CSS?

Tags: selenium

I want to fine this `WebElement`:

```
<div class="title_bar bar ng-sss" ng-rr="!isBulkMode">
```

So when using `CSS`:

```
div[class=title_bar bar ng-sss]
```

This element could not found.

And with `Xpath` this works:

```
//div[@class='title_bar bar ng-sss']
```

Comment: Cause the css is wrong.

Comment: Why wrong ? can you show example ?

Comment: Try `div.title_bar.bar.ng-sss`

Comment: There is no such thing as "class with space in the name"! It is a space-separated **list** of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have apostrophes in the `cssSelector`

```
By.cssSelector("div[class=`title_bar bar ng-sss`]");
```

You also don't have to use square brackets when using `cssSelector`

```
By.cssSelector("div.title_bar.bar.ng-sss`]");
// or
By.cssSelector(".title_bar.bar.ng-sss`]");
```

Dot before the name represents class name.